# connection line is hidden when div1 and div2 in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

there are 2 divs, box1 and box2 and are connected by `.line`. Connection line is working fine when 'box1' in left of `box2` or `box1` in right of 'box2'.However, if both are in same line(one in top and other one  on bottom) line is removed !

> why connection line is removed when divs in same line ?

```js
$(function () {
$('.box').draggable().on('drag', function () {
    var x1 = $('.box1').position().left;
    var y1 = $('.box1').position().top;
    var x2 = $('.box2').position().left;
    var y2 = $('.box2').position().top;
    
    if (x1 > x2) {  
        var x3 = x1;
        var y3 = y1;
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
        x2 = x3;
        y2 = y3;
    }
    if (x1 == x2  ) {  
        $('.line').css({
            height: Math.abs(y2 - y1),
            left: x1 + ($('.box1').width() / 2),
            width: 1,
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'zoom': 1
        });
    } else {  // else calculate angle and rotate line
        var a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        var radians = Math.atan(a);
        var degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
        $('.line').css({
            top: y1 + ($('.box1').height() / 2),
            left: x1 + ($('.box1').width() / 2),
            width: Math.abs(x2 - x1),
            height: 1,
            'transform-origin': '0 0',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            'zoom': 1
        });
    }
});
});
```

```css
.box{ draggable:true; position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; background:red; cursor:move; }
.box1{ top:25px; }
.box2{ left:200px; }
.line{ height:1px; width:1px; background:blue; position:absolute; -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%; -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%; transform-origin:0% 0%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="box1 box"></div>
    <div class="box2 box"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Where's your code? You need to have a [mcve] in your question

Comment: @j08691 code is added to the  question.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? The line is not always drawn exactly in the center of each square, this not only happens when one is above the other.

Comment: Expected behavior is that the connection line must be always connected and visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate distance between 1 points using both axles now only by X in your case when x1 != x2:

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

In JS:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2))
```

```js
$(function () {
$('.box').draggable().on('drag', function () {
    var x1 = $('.box1').position().left;
    var y1 = $('.box1').position().top;
    var x2 = $('.box2').position().left;
    var y2 = $('.box2').position().top;
    
    if (x1 > x2) {  
        var x3 = x1;
        var y3 = y1;
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
        x2 = x3;
        y2 = y3;
    }
    if (x1 == x2  ) {  
        $('.line').css({
            height: Math.abs(y2 - y1),
            left: x1 + ($('.box1').width() / 2),
            width: 1,
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'zoom': 1
        });
    } else {  // else calculate angle and rotate line
        var a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        var radians = Math.atan(a);
        var degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
        $('.line').css({
            top: y1 + ($('.box1').height() / 2),
            left: x1 + ($('.box1').width() / 2),
            width: Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2)),
            height: 1,
            'transform-origin': '0 0',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
            'zoom': 1
        });
    }
});
});
```

```css
.box{ draggable:true; position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; background:red; cursor:move; }
.box1{ top:25px; }
.box2{ left:200px; }
.line{ height:1px; width:1px; background:blue; position:absolute; -moz-transform-origin:0% 0%; -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%; transform-origin:0% 0%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="box1 box"></div>
    <div class="box2 box"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```